# Implement Moq Unit Test and Actual Unit Test methods in same class

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

Need to implement Moq Unit Test and Actual Unit Test in same test class , with help of some config file key. 
Is it possible to do so using same object which will be assigned based on the config value ?

Means if config file key is "Moq" then Moq Unit Test will run and if not Actual Unit Test will run in same test class and in same method .

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking.  I've never heard of a distinction between an Moq unit test and an "actual" unit test; could you elaborate?

Comment: You should be more specific. I really don't know what u are talking about.

Comment: Sorry . Means there are two ways we can implement Unit test 

1. Mocking the result using certain frameworks , Moq which I am using .
2. Actual Unit test call , which will directly call the database to get the actual data.
I want to implement both in same Test method which can be managed using config value . 

Means if I set 1 then Moq Unit testing should happen and
If I set 2 Actual Unit Test should happen .

Comment: So the second test is not a unit-test, it's an Integration Tests.

Comment: Sorry I may be wrong . 
We can do unit testing without Mocking also right ? 
So if we try to run the test then if there are any database calls , then it will make the calls to get the real time data ? Right  ? 
If I am using a helper object which does the database calls , then I want create a dynamic object which will be initialized on TestInitialize  where a condition is made to set either 
helperobject = new Mock<HelperClass>();
or 
helperobject = new HelperClass();

which either Moq the return value or get the real value ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, but likely it's not the best practice. 
For example,

```
public class MyClass
{
   IDependency _d;
   public MyClass(IDependency d)
   {
      _d = d;
   }
}
public class Dependency : IDependency
{
}
```

In the test class, I can have something like this:

```
[TestClass]
public class MyClassTests
{
   MyClass _sut;
   Mock<IDependency> _mockDependency;
   Dependency _realDependency;
   [TestInit]
   public void Init()
   {
      var shouldUseMock = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["key"];
      if(shouldUseMock)
      {
         _mockDependency = new Mock<IDependency>();
        _sut = new MyClass(_mockDependency.Object) 
      }
      else
      {
        _realDependency = new Dependency();
        _sut = new MyClass(_realDependency);
      }
   }
}
```

The problem will be setting up expectations based on different situations and it makes the test class much harder to maintain. You should rather create two tests, one real unit test with the `mock` and the other kind of integration test with real implementation.